# Display string formula not used when exporting from Crystal Reports XI

Tags: crystal-reports, export, crystal-reports-xi, export-to-csv

I've produced a report in Crystal Reports XI where I in one of the fields have used the display string formula to alter the apperance of some data as well as group similar data values to one value (e.g. "neg", "negative", and "-" now all displays as "negative" in the report.)

However, now when I export the report to CSV for delivery to a customer the raw data, and not the display string formula result, is in the export. I've tried all 4 settings with the checkboxes in the CSV export options.

Is there any way to make the display string formatted data beeing exported to the CSV?
Are there any alternate ways of achiving the desired formatting and getting the formatting preserved in CSV export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, i've not found a way of using the display string formula and achieving the desired result.

Instead create a new formula and replace the object on the report with the new formula.

L